# Will Google index my site like this?

Tags: html, url, query-string

Suppose I have a URL in my query string. Someone told me that Google does not like it because they believe we are pulling content from another server.

```
http://mydomain.com/?id=http://abc.com
```

Comment: Use a sitemap... and URLEncode the address; it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I URL encode the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google Webmaster tools, it will report back to you any problems that it has with urls in your site. It just takes a bit of time for them to spider your site, but the reporting is useful.

Comment: There are no problems with Webmaster Tools

Comment: Cool, like aviraldg says, use a sitemap, but I think it will still be worth reading the material that you find in Webmaster Tools help. Better to find out how google works from them.